# createObjectURL size limit on Cloud9 server

Tags: html, google-chrome, cloud9-ide

I am working on using createObjectURL to create a file from a blob in a cloud9 workspace.

```
function saveFile(blob, fileName) {
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  console.log("blob to be saved, and its size is "+blob.size);
  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = fileName;
  link.click();
}
```

the console logs the blob size correctly. However, I found an interesting issue. Chrome can save file less than 4MB but throws file not found for any file over 4MB. and the error logs below

blob:https%3A//?????-??????.c9.io/688e940f-c94c-4050-a081-466569c8de57

I am wondering if it has anything to do with Cloud9 server limit? I dont know if I understand createObjectURL method correctly, but i think everything is done on client side, and should have nothing to do with server? Maybe i am wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting the blob from?

Comment: I am getting the chunked blob from webRTC dataChannel, and on receiving end, I construct the chunked blobs into the original file blob. it works perfectly fine files less than 4MB..